# Should you check to make sure your employer is paying you the correct superannuation amount? [Australia]

Tags: australia, contribution, employment-law

Most people just assume their super is correct and is put in and I bet most people don't even check, but how do you really know if it's being paid?

Is there heaps of checks and balances that businesses have to do to make it not worth their while to cheat you out of your super?

Comment: What's a super?

Comment: Wikipedia says *Superannuation is a retirement (including pensions) program in Australia. It has a compulsory element whereby employers are required by law to pay an additional amount based on a proportion of an employee's salaries and wages (currently 9%) into a complying superannuation fund ...* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superannuation_in_Australia

Comment: BTW, great question.  I've also been waiting for somebody to ask about the Australian superannuation plans.  We have so few Australian questions relative to U.S., Canada, U.K.  So, +1 ;-)

Comment: oh wow, i didn't realize that superannuation only existed in Australia!

Comment: "*Are* there heaps"

Answer (score 2):

As poolie mentioned, you should get online access to your account.

This will do a couple of things:

1. You will think about super regularly.
2. You can change your investment plan. I'm no advisor, but if you are young, you want high-growth.
3. You can see the money going in. You will think about super.

Also, consolidate any super you have with different companies. Now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are checks and balances.  Employers can be, and have been, prosecuted for failing to pay super before the statutory timeline, which is three months from the pay date.

**However, it is still in your interests to check for yourself.**  The most common point for missing super to be discovered is when the company goes broke, at which point it's too late for you.

What you should do is

- Check on your payslips that the right amount is allocated to super.  It should be 9% of gross, plus any salary sacrifice or additional component.
- Check your super fund's half-yearly statements line up the deductions given on your payslip.
- Consider getting online access to your super account so you can check more quickly.
- If something is missing, call your super fund and/or payroll office.

Resources:

- http://www.fido.gov.au/fido/fido.nsf/byHeadline/Keeping%20track%20of%20your%20superannuation
- http://www.ato.gov.au/unpaidsuper